How to trigger custom events during Stencil e2e tests?
I have that Stencil component:
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'root.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  handleUploadedFile(event: CustomEvent): void {
    console.log(event.detail.name, event.detail.arrayBuffer())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <file-import onFileUploaded={event => this.handleUploadedFile(event)} />
      </Host>
    );
  }
}

and I am trying to simulate an event from FileImportComponent:
describe('testing file import', () => {
    it('should work', async () => {
        const page = await newE2EPage();
        await page.setContent(`<my-component></my-component>`);
        const fileImportComponent = await page.find('my-component >>> file-import');

        const mockFile = {
            arrayBuffer: () => Promise.resolve(new Uint32Array([1, 2]) as ArrayBuffer)
            name: 'filename',
        }
        console.log('fn', mockFile.name, mockFile.arrayBuffer)

        fileImportComponent.triggerEvent('fileUploaded', { detail: mockFile });
        await page.waitForChanges();
    });
});

the thing is: in my test file, mockFile.name and mockFile.arrayBuffer are properly defined; but in my component, mockFile.name exists and mockFile.arrayBuffer is not defined!
Is it possible to pass triggerEvent an object with methods or it is not supported?
